# Travel from USA to Mexico as a refugee document holder - Can I use my home country passport?

Tags: usa, passports, mexico, refugees, chinese-citizens

My wife is an asylee. Status was granted. Still waiting on I-485. She has a travel document and we want to visit Mexico for vacation. Mexican consulate will issue entrance visa but my wife is getting it stamped into her Chinese passport. And expects the travel document to be sufficient for re entry into the USA. My suggestion was to leave the valid home passport home and use travel document. Does anyone know if this may cause a problem when we re-enter the USA. I think so as she will be traveling as a citizen of the prc while she has status as assyle. Any help would be welcome.thank you.

Comment: According to https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/applying-refugee-travel-document.html travel outside the U.S. with a valid travel document always carries some risk that you might not be allowed to reenter. It is safer to delay travel abroad until you can do so with a green card.

Answer (score 6):

The I-571 Refugee Travel Document is perfectly sufficient for re-entering the US. You should have no trouble with it unless you do something that makes the US question your status as an asylee... such as using the passport of the country you claimed asylum from.

It is a very, very bad idea to continue to use that passport in a way that the US might find out about it. If the US learns you are still using it, your asylee status could be revoked. This also means it's a very bad idea to have the Mexican visa placed in it. The details of everyone's departure from the US by air is passed to the government by the airlines; this is how the US does not have exit immigration controls as most countries do. If your departure is recorded on the passport of the country you claimed asylum from, your status is at risk.

You should apply for the Mexican visa with your Refugee Travel Document instead. This is perfectly safe and you do not have to worry about entering Mexico or returning to the US.

Comment: +1 True: **It is a very, very bad idea to continue to use that passport in a way that the US might find out about it. If the US learns you are still using it, your asylee status could be revoked. This also means it's a very bad idea to have the Mexican visa placed in it.** Please do not do this. In the current political environment, the chances your wife's asylum claim will be revoked are high.